# Python while if not working

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I'm given with an array with numbers.
I'm trying to build a program that identifies if the number is an even or odd number.
Here's what I've done.

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
i=0
while i <= len(a):
    if a[i] % 2 == 0:
        print(a[i], " is an even number")
        i = i + 1
    else:
        print(a[i], " is an odd number")
```

I was thinking since a[0], a[1] represents 1, 4, I thought that I can use a[i] where i increases until the length of a.
But this code gives me an infinite loop.

This is the only way I figured to use individual numbers in array.
I tried using

```
if a%2==0:
    print(a, " is an even number")
```

But that gave me an error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Python indices are 0 based, so the highest index in a list is length - 1. Your condition should be `i < len(a)`, not `i <= len(a)`.

Comment: you only increment `i` when you find an even number - when `i` is odd its value never changes.

Comment: I think this question is being unfairly downvoted, especially given that the poster is explaining the problem and what they've tried to do to fix it.

Comment: @MarcTalbot I see no attempts to debug the problem. The `a%2==0` code doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that simply with a `for` loop like below:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
for n in a:
    if n % 2:
        print(n, "is an odd number")
    else:
        print(n, "is an even number")
```

For your above code issues, you are not incrementing `i` inside `else` block and your condition should be `< len(a)` instead of `<= len(a)`

Comment: True, and much more elegant, but it does not explain why the `while` loop is not working.

Comment: You can even reduce the code inside the `for` loop to: `print('{} is an {} number.'.format(n, 'odd' if n % 2 else 'even'))`

Answer (score 1):

Put your i = i+1 outside of the if/else and replace <= with a < otherwise it goes over the array length.

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
i=0
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] % 2 == 0:
        print(a[i], " is an even number")
    else:
        print(a[i], " is an odd number")
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: You also have to fix the condition to use `<` instead of `<=`

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that the following:

instead of using  <=  use  <.

Add your i = i + 1 in both if and else. 
Because if you hit an even number it will add 1 to i, but also if you hit a odd number it will add 1 too.

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
i=0
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] % 2 == 0:
        print(a[i], " is an even number")
        i = i + 1
    else:
        print(a[i], " is an odd number")
        i = i + 1
```

Then if you use this code:

```
if a%2==0:
    print(a, " is an even number")
```

What happens here is that the variable "a" is a list and to loop through it you need to break up the list into single components as you did "a[i]". What you are doing here is taking the list as a single component and not breaking up the list to get each value of the list.

Hope you get it.